# Crear Calendario con pivot SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente caso.
Tengo una tabla con el siguiente nombre AUT_CALENDARIO donde tengo como datos ingresados los meses, días de semana de todo el año de la siguiente manera.

Esta es mi estructura:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que estoy queriendo obtener de esta tabla es la siguiente estructura

IDCALENDARIO | LUNES | MARTES | MIERCOLES | JUEVES | VIERNES | SABADO | DOMINGO
20220201       1        2          3          4        5         6        7

y asi sucesivamente hasta completar los dias de febrero o del mes correspondiente.

Tengo el siguiente query donde estoy tratando de realizar mediante un PIVOT la estructura planteada.

```js
SELECT IDCALENDARIO,NombreDia, [Lunes], [Martes], [Miercoles], [Jueves], [Viernes], [Sabado], [Domingo]
FROM (
    SELECT IDCALENDARIO,NombreDia, DATENAME(dw, FECHA) AS DayWeek, DIA
    FROM AUT_CALENDARIO where FECHA between '2022-02-01' and '2022-02-28'
    ) AS src
    pivot (
        sum(DIA) FOR DayWeek IN ([Lunes], [Martes], [Miercoles], [Jueves], [Viernes], [Sabado], [Domingo])
    ) AS pvt
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente resultado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual no cumple con lo que estoy tratando de obtener.

Talvez tengan otra idea o si pivot no es lo ideas o mi estructura de mi tabala esta mal diseñada.

Seria de mucha ayuda aun estoy iniciando en este mundo.

Comment: Hola Kenny: ¿Cuál es la salida esperada? NO importa lo que obtienes, sino lo que quieres obtener. Edita la pregunta y pon lo que quieres que te devuelva la consulta. Además en vez de pegar una imagen con lo que tienes, puedes crear un script con las sentencias de creación e inserción de las mínimas filas necesarias, o sqlFiddle con el origen, para que todos los que quieran ayudarte no tengan que reproducir tu escenario cada vez.

Comment: ok lo tendre en cuenta gracias.